# Is "rightsayer" a word?

Tags: nouns, word-usage

Is "rightsayer" a word that describes someone that believes themselves to always be right?

Comment: No, per current lexicons. Furthermore, there seem to be no evidence of usage per Google search.

Comment: Related: [Word for someone that always has to be right](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55540/word-for-someone-that-always-has-to-be-right/)

Comment: @Mohit They are not related.

Comment: @kris - Agreed. Deleted.

Answer (score 1):

There do not appear to be any dictionary entries for this word. Even Urban Dictionary does not have anything. It is not, at any rate, an antonym for naysayer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in Indian English?  I found this from Googling...

> But would you rather believe someone who said - Krishna said it is so?
>
> Actually, I have found that when you (I) say anything, the first question is always - who said that?
> "I said it" is somehow not so convincing.
> You have to become an established rightsayer, and then suddenly others think every sneese you make is the absolute truth.

link: http://www.gaudiya-repercussions.com/index.php?showtopic=2861